# Why is Guard Livereload not starting the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, livereload

I have setup Guard and Guar-Livereload on my new Rails project similarly on how I had on a previous one: Gemfile:

```
group :development do
    gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
    gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
    gem 'childprocess'
    gem "rspec-rails"
    gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
    gem 'spring'
    gem "guard-rspec"
end
```

And in my Guardfile:

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)$})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{app/assets/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{app/assets/.+\.(css|js|scss|jpg|png)})
  watch(%r{public/.+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
  # Rails Assets Pipeline
  watch(%r{(app|vendor)(/assets/\w+/(.+\.(css|js|html|png|jpg))).*}) { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
end
```

Which was created after issuing the command `guard init guard-livereload`. When I issue `guard` I can see the following messages:

```
18:35:41 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
18:35:43 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
18:35:43 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
18:35:43 - INFO - Guard is now watching at             '/Volumes/volume/Users/myuser/Documents/RubyApps/myapp'
[1] guard(main)>
```

But the server doesn't start, however if I `rails s` the server will start and visible on the front end. This leads me to believe the issue is with Guard. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

**EDIT Added console after running `guard -d`:**

```
18:31:56 - DEBUG - Command execution: emacsclient --eval '1' 2> /dev/null || echo 'N/A'
18:31:56 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
18:31:57 - DEBUG - Command execution: hash stty
18:31:57 - DEBUG - Guard starts all plugins
18:31:57 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::RSpec
18:31:57 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
18:31:57 - DEBUG - Hook :start_end executed for Guard::RSpec
18:31:57 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::LiveReload
18:31:57 - DEBUG - Hook :start_end executed for Guard::LiveReload
18:31:57 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
18:31:57 - INFO - Guard is now watching at    '/Volumes/fenix/Users/wagner/Documents/htdocs/RubyApps/turing'
18:31:57 - DEBUG - Start interactor
18:31:57 - DEBUG - Command execution: stty -g 2>/dev/null`
```

Answer (score 0):

look at [@ec2](https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/689#issuecomment-65350801)'s recent comment on this:

> for livereload, run guard with the '-d' option (bundle exec guard -d) and you should see Hook :run_on_modifications_begin executed for Guard::LiveReload. Let us know if you get that message or not (next step depends on the answer). And of course, make sure livereload is actually turned on in your browser (I have to enable it every time I start the project) - ideally, just open a static html file in the browser, edit that file and check - it should work.

Comment: I've run as you've suggested and did not get the `Hook:run_on_modification_begin` message. I've edited my question to add the message

Comment: Could you post your whole `Guardfile`?